# update <p:tab only in jsf page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabs, tabview

```
 <p:tab title="Temperature Analysis" rendered="#{!userBean.user.temperatureNotAllow}">

                            <p:outputPanel id="temperatureAnalysisPanel" >
                                <h:form style="margin-left: 800px">
                                    <h:outputText value="Select Y-Axis Range"></h:outputText>
                                    <h:panelGrid columns="5" cellspacing="9">


                                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-left:  0px">
                                        <h:outputText id="displayRange" value="Between #{generatorDataLogBean.minRangeForTemp} and #{generatorDataLogBean.maxRangeForTemp}" />
                                        <p:slider  for="txt6,txt7" display="displayRange" style="width: 130px; margin-top: 0px" range="true" displayTemplate="Between {min} and {max}" step="10" minValue="-50" maxValue="150" >
                                            <p:ajax event="slideEnd" process="txt6,txt7"  />
                                        </p:slider>
                                    </h:panelGrid>

                                    <h:inputHidden id="txt6" value="#{generatorDataLogBean.minRangeForTemp}" />
                                    <h:inputHidden id="txt7" value="#{generatorDataLogBean.maxRangeForTemp}" />
                                    <p:commandButton  value="Change" style="width: 70px; height: 30px; margin-left: 15px" actionListener="#{generatorDataLogReportBean.changeGraph(generatorDataLogBean.maxRangeForTemp,generatorDataLogBean.minRangeForTemp)}" ajax="false" update=":movementTabview:temperatureAnalysisPanel"  />


                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </h:form>    

                                <p:chart type="line" model="#{generatorDataLogReportBean.animatedModel1}" style="width:98%;"/>
                                <br/>


                            </p:outputPanel>


                        </p:tab>
```

in my jsf page i want to update only single tab but when I pressed commandButton its update whole page how can I handle it?
My tabView is under this:

```
   <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                    <p:tabView id="movementTabview" dynamic="true">
```

Comment: That is exactly as designed when using `ajax='false'`

Comment: Yes it is due this. Thank you

Comment: Next time start creating an [mcve]. In the proces of doing so, you might find solutions like this

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are not using any id for `<p:tab>` try to assign some id and then update like this `update=":movementTabview:tabId:temperatureAnalysisPanel"`